# Outdoor cameras, all-weather, day and night, raspberryPI, etc

Tags: camera

Disclaimer: I really do not know much about cameras.

Background: I would like to have a camera outside. The camera must be able to record during both the day and night (night vision? infrared?), different weather conditions, and I would like decent resolution - enough to be able to identify e.g. birds in the sky at a distance, see stars, etc.

I want to be able to stream the video recording in real-time to a RaspberryPI, Arduino, or some other development board.

Question: What are some good cameras that I could look into purchasing?

Comment: this is not a Raspberry Pi question ... please edit your question to be about the RPi and not to be a shopping question

Comment: @jsotola It also could be answered by a quick Google search even for someone who isn't very familiar with the Pi or Arduino. It isn't even a very subjective question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a Raspberry Pi you could use a [Dual camera adapter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RWKg5.png) and mount the [Camera Module V2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/camera-module-v2/) along with the [NoIR version](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/pi-noir-camera-v2/) of it, or you could connect it to two [HQ Cammera modules](https://www.raspberrypi.org/products/raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/) with one of them having the IR filter removed. Use the HQ only if you need the quality (you'd also need to buy your own lenses).

You can use any standard camea module like this for the arduino with 5$:
[image: Camera Module for the Arduino]

As for weather you could just make a simple case out of cardboard or buy one if you're using a Picamera. You could also [3D print one](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/3d-printable-cases-for-the-raspberry-pi-high-quality-camera/) if you're paranoid.

Comment: Thank you very much! I had read about the NoIR cameras, but had no idea about the HQ Camera module, nor about the Dual camera adapter. The HQ Camera module looks grand.